# KineticJS: Animate an item to go back to initial position when not dropped in drop target

Tags: drag-and-drop, kineticjs

I made an application which performs drag and drop of different items: images and shapes. I limited the drop target to a specific layer: `rightLayer` in my case using a simple test with `if ... else`. Everything works great, except that I want to make an item **revert back to its original position** in the leftLayer when it doesn't attempt the borders of rightLayer (just like jquery, but in **kineticJS**). Or just disappear instantly.

Here's a **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GLFxF/28/)** . For a better understanding, try this use case:

- drag the rectangle,
- drop it right before the grid,
- click on an item from the left layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can self-destruct any clone dropped other than in the dropzone with a test in `dragend`.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2T68g/

```
clone1.on("dragend",function(){

    // destroy this clone if dropped outside the dropzone

    if(this.x()<dropzone.x()){ 
        this.destroy();
        layer.draw();
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add the last two lines. So there is no way to do the animation, like revert?

Comment: Sure!  In `clone1.on("dragstart"` save the XY of the original node. Then in the if() condition create a Kinetic.Tween that moves the clone back on top of the original node.  Add an onFinish callback to the Tween which destroys the clone.

Comment: Thanks again :) I didn't know Kinetic.Tween even exists. I'll give it a try and post an edited jsfiddle later.

Comment: You're welcome :-)  Here's a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Ffpn3/  Good luck with your project!